# Are there Windows services which only run on IPv6?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, ipv6, windows-10

This network has about 30 Windows-10 computers and all DNS, DHCP, Active Directory, etc. services are provided by Windows 2012 R2.

Are there any native services; be it critical, optional, useless, or otherwise; that would be impaired or unable to function if the native IPv6 stack and all the tricks Windows uses to send IPv6 traffic over IPv4 are disabled?

I know the advantages and disadvantages of IPv6 from a networking perspective, but this is simply Windows and Windows services.

Comment: Are you asking if IPv6 can reasonably be disabled?

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to what is so critical about IPv6 connectivity that Microsoft that they would not only develop teredo from the ground up but also be the only sponsor for its RFC [link](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4380). IPv6 must serve some core function, otherwise why work so hard to have it connect? I just don't have a way to test it.

Comment: Yes, can IPv6 be reasonably be disabled? Not only the native stack but also the other tools windows uses to get IPv6 connectivity.

Comment: No, you cannot disable IPv6, at least not if you want support from Microsoft. You _can_, however, disable IPv4 and still be in a supported configuration. (But it's fine to disable IPv6 transition technologies, and it's usually a good idea to do so, unless you're actually using them.)

Comment: @MichaelHampton do you have any documents which support your claim of support from Microsoft?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IPv6 [is a mandatory component](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929852) since Windows Vista, and therefore it is strongly recommended not to disable it.  Should you do that, you'll be unable to reach any host that uses IPv6.  Therefore it's a matter of network addressing, rather than services.

I'm not aware of any service that only uses IPv6, which was anyway made to be backward-compatible with IPv4.

Comment: I really like your link, but are there more things like this? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/983276